# Loop Through A Function Parameter / Images Created With A `new Image()` Instance

Tags: function, loops, parameters, blob

I have an image thumbnail that is created using `new Image()` which essentially shows thumbnails of images that are to be uploaded prior to form submission.

I have PHP validations that handle the uploads on the backend. If an image is less than 4 MB the image uploads fail in the backend and I would like to append a message to the particular thumbnail in regard to this with javascript.

The function below is called within the form with an `oninput` attribute and takes a parameter `file`.

**The Problem**

Because I'm essentially looping through the `file` parameter, I can't work out how to loop the images created by the `new Image()` instance each time, so it only shows the error on the relevant image.

Any help much appreciated.

```
function updateThumbnail(file) {
    if (file.type.startsWith('image/')) {

        let 
        uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement('figure'),
        thumbnailElement = new Image();
    
        // image thumbnail
        thumbnailElement.classList.add('drop-zone__thumb')
        thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    
        // appending elements
        showSelectedImages.append(uploadImageWrapper) // <figure> element
        uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement) // image thumbnail

        // error messaging for file size
        let thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-zone__thumb'),
        sizeError = `<p>Image must be bigger than 4MB</p>`

        thumbnails.forEach(img => {
            if (img.size < 4000000) {
                img.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', sizeError)
            }
        })

        console.log(img.size)
        console.log(thumbnailElement)

    }

} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function

// ---  updateThumbnail(file) is called in the HTML with an `oninput` attribute in the form
```

Comment: why don't you just do `thumbnailElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', sizeError)` if `file` has size smaller than required?

Comment: @Juraj - that worked. That's really confused me though why it works without a loop? because there are multiple instances of the image I thought it would have to loop through them. If you put that as answer I'll mark it as correct so you get the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function handles one image file and adds a thumbnail for it, so why not handle the sizeError only for that image file at that time.

Just do:

```
if (file.size < 4000000) {
  thumbnailElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', sizeError);
}
```

and remove the `thumbnails` variable and the code around.